# Can't find document at lucene index with no delimeter in phrase

Tags: lucene

I have document with text field fullName (the text is '**1a**'). It saved to lucene index and indexed with custom analyzer (which contains *WordDelimeterGraph* filter with *splitOnNumerics = 0* parameter).

The problem is that I can search that document only by query '**1 a**', not '1a'. Why?!

As I know *WordDelimeterGraph* filter (with splitOnNumerics = 0 parameter) must not(!) split literal and numeric to search the text '1a' as is...

Indexing and searching are used the custom analyzer with the following filters:

- whitespace tokenizer
- lowercase filter (splitOnCaseChange=0, spltOnNumerics=0, protected=protected.txt)
- stop filter (ignoreCaseTrue=0, format=snowball, words=words.txt)

Maybe anybody know the reason of it. I don't have any ideas. Thanks!

P.S. I use lucene core version 9.0.0 (also reproduced on version 9.10.0).